# TypeORM - connectionNotFoundError

Tags: typescript, express, typeorm

i created a project with Typescript + Typeorm + Express. But when run dev script returns this error: `connectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found`

My ormconfig.json:

```json
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "docker",
  "database": "clean-node-api",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "./src/infra/typeorm/entities/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/infra/typeorm/migrations"
  }
}
```

Link of repository: https://github.com/thuram/typescript-api-with-tdd

Answer (score 0):

I have cloned your repo and run your code.I found the backtrace

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
    at new ConnectionNotFoundError (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/error/ConnectionNotFoundError.ts:8:9)
    at ConnectionManager.get (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:40:19)
    at Object.getRepository (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/index.ts:287:35)
    at new UserRepository (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/infra/typeorm/repositories/UserRepository.ts:14:26)
    at Object.exports.makeCreateUser (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/main/factories/useCases/user/CreateUserFactory.ts:5:26)
    at Object.exports.makeSignUpController (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/main/factories/controllers/user/SignUpControllerFactory.ts:6:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/src/main/routes/SignUp.ts:5:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/lithium/develop/typescript-api-with-tdd/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:547:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/private/var/folders/fx/7f3mc02s4lxbzjmzvw4cmknh0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-1775948954112352.js:57:33)
[ERROR] 10:41:29 ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
```

The error raised from `UserRepository.ts:14:26)`,

```
  constructor() {
    this.ormRepository = getRepository(User);
  }
```

So you are trying to create a repository or manager without the connection being established.So put this statement `const repo = await getRepository(User);` into a function will work!